# Magento Front-End Nothing Display.

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, server, hosting, localhost

Magento Front-End Nothing Display. 
I Changed My Magento Site to Live Hosting.
I Can Login Admin Panel that everything ok but Front-End Nothing Display.

Comment: did you check your log files? also you can on developer mode from index.php

Comment: check sever memory_limit

Comment: how can check memory_limit @meen..

Comment: `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M'); ` add this code in you index.php after `<?php` and check if page get load. Then you need to change that in server settings(i.e, php.ini) file

Answer (score 2):

1. Change the base Url for both secure and unsecure front end.
2. Change the database connections in local.xml
3. Try to clear the cache and session folder.
4. If any licensed extension then change the license key for the local host.

Comment: i can login admin panel , change all base url path & also cache  disabled

Comment: Probably 4.May licensed extension then change the license key for the demo  host. How can I check it?

Comment: Open the configuration settings of your custom module if any. And check any license key is available in the setting.